# SQL select by field acting weird

Tags: sql, jpa, select, orm, identity

I am writing this post because I have encountered something truly weird with an SQL statement I am trying to make.

**Context:**

I am developing an app which uses JPA in the backend to persist / retrieve objects to/from a postgres database.

**Problem:**

During some tests I have noticed that when a particular user adds entries in the database and later I try to fetch them by his facebook id, the result is an empty list, even though the entries are there in the database. Doing a select statement on the database returns no rows. This does not happen with other users. 
I have noticed that the mentioned user's facebook id is slightly longer then others. I do not know if and how this affects this situation.

**Interesting part:** 
When during debugging I created an entry not programmatically, but manually with a SQL INSERT statement directly on the database (marked red on the 1st screenshot), I could fetch the data by facebook id both in my app and with a select statement.

Do you have any ideas what is going on here? 
Please check the screenshots:
result of `select * from table:`

[image: result of "select * from table]
result of `select * from table where user_facebook_id = 10215905779020408` :
[image]

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the user adding said entries commits changes to the database after inserting rows?

Comment: And another question, what is the datatype of `user_facebook_id` column? Is it a number or a string? Maybe there's a dangling whitespace somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I am pretty sure changes are commited, I use spring data JPA's `saveAndFlush()`. And the described issue does not happen with other testing users.
As for the second question - it is of type Long (so bigint in sql I guess)

Comment: Will `select distinct user_facebook_id from table;` yield the value once/twice?

Comment: BTW: Have you really named a table `table`?

Comment: The query you posted yields the value twice. 
Haha, no, it's not called table, I just wrote `table` to avoid confusion (perhaps I accidentally caused some :) ). 
Something crazy now - if I go `select * from table where user_facebook_id = 10215905779020407` (id lower by 1) - the missing rows are returned. With the user facebook id ending with 408. What the hell.

Comment: hmm, facebook id is an id field in another entity - User. I set it's value manually after logging through facebook. Perhaps it is automatically increased by one by some sort of ID auto-generation mechanism. In the User entity I only added an annotation "@Id", nothing about automatic generation. This is weird though, as for other users nothing like that is happening.

Comment: Would you please also check `select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table';`? How was the schema/table created?

Comment: returned dataType for user_facebook_id column is bigint. It was created automatically by hibernate (mapped from Entity classes).

Comment: seems like it is an issue with the database itself. I am using ElephantSQL postgres as a service db. When I create a new user with a db INSERT statement, the shown id is different from the one that I input (by one). Then, the newly inserted row is only found with the SELECT statement with the original value. But the returned row has the changed value anyway.
Example:
`INSERT INTO users (facebook_id, email, facebook_name) values (10215905779020401, 'email', 'name')` adds a row with id `10215905779020400`. Now, `SELECT (...) where facebook_id = 10215905779020400` returns no rows

Comment: but `SELECT (...) where facebook_id = 10215905779020401` returns a row. And the row's displayed id ends with 400.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily blame the database in the first place. What database client are you using to display the results? And one more, please check `select distinct to_char(facebook_id) from table;`. Do the string values differ from the numeric ones?

Comment: this query results in an error:
`ERROR:  function to_char(bigint) does not exist
LINE 1: select distinct to_char(user_facebook_id) from wishes;
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: I must have messed up, because `to_char()` gets two args: input and format. Try this way `select distinct to_char(facebook_id, 'fm9999999999999999999999999999999999') from table;` Or maybe cast will work: `select distinct facebook_id::TEXT from table;`.